# Java FXML Can't seem to clear the ArrayList I am printing

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So I am making a pizza ordering form. It is supposed to clear every time I click "Add Pizza" allowing me to make another pizza and add it onto the same order. Except the toppings don't clear from the first pizza. I am trying with just two toppings first (Ham and Pepperoni). But it doesn't seem to clear even though I use clear().

This is my clear method:

```
 private void clearScreen(){
  pizzaSm.setSelected(false);
  pizzaMed.setSelected(false);
  pizzaLg.setSelected(false);
  crust1.setSelected(false);
  crust2.setSelected(false);
  crust3.setSelected(false);
  pepperoni.setSelected(false);
  ham.setSelected(false);
  bacon.setSelected(false);
  sausage.setSelected(false);
  chicken.setSelected(false);
  pineapple.setSelected(false);
  mushroom.setSelected(false);
  olives.setSelected(false);
  redOnion.setSelected(false);
  spinach.setSelected(false);
  pizzaTotal.setText("");
  pizzaTotalTaxed.setText("");
  orderAdd.clear();
```

This is my Add Pizza method

```
  private void addPizza (ActionEvent event){

    Pizzas p = new Pizzas(size,crust,topping,topping1,price,tax,total);
    orderAdd.add(p);
    orderAdd.forEach(System.out::println);
    clearScreen();
}
```

And this is the input and output.
input: [http://i.imgur.com/jJRw4KT.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUHj1.png)

output : Your Pizza: Medium, Regular Crust,  - Pepperoni Cost : $14.0 $1.82 $15.82

**This is where it gets confusing for me.
If I choose a different input, the output will still keep the pepperoni there.**

input: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKOtr.png)

output: Your Pizza: Medium, Regular Crust,  - Ham - Pepperoni Cost : $17.0 $2.21 $19.21

Comment: i think you should clear values for `size,crust,topping,topping1,price,tax,total` as well in your `clearScreen` method

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Simply reset values , like `size = null`